# Historical Constituents S&P 500

Tags: historical-data

In order to backtest a few strategies I'm searching for a (free) csv/excel file of tickers included in the s&p 500 during specified years (say, 1970).

Do you happen to know where I can find something like this? I tried searching but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: You have to pay for the official data. Some amateurs have constructed an approximate history from public data, going back to the early 2000's at best (I don't know any free one that goes back to 1970). Two examples are https://robotwealth.com/how-to-get-historical-spx-constituents-data-for-free/ and https://analyzingalpha.com/sp500-historical-components-and-changes TBH I don't know the quality of these attempts

Comment: What @noob2 said. You can confirm those against the [wikipedia data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies) (current constituents and deltas back 20 years).

Comment: @noob2 Thank you for the info. Should it be easier to get total market tickers from 1970 instead of just tickers included in the S&P 500?

Answer (score 1):

Market data is rarely free, but if you're willing to pay for it, S&P 500 historical constituents data is available from Sharadar in QuantRocket's [Data Library](https://www.quantrocket.com/data/?filter=sharadar), with history back to 1957.